# Equivalent of C# type constraint (where) in Scala

Tags: scala

In C# you can define a method

```
public T GetComponent<T>() where T : IComponent
```

to express that T has to be of IComponent.

How can I express the same in Scala?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Scala, this is called an [Upper Type Bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/upper-type-bounds.html) (as you can also have a [Lower Type Bound](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/lower-type-bounds), a constraint that doesn't exist in C#). You define them like this:

```
def getComponent[T <: IComponent]
```